# Error Variable might not have been initialised

Tags: java, initialization

For some reason I'm getting these two errors listed below.

```
Error variable fahrenhuit might not have been initialized.
Error variable kelvin might not have been initialized.
```

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class TemperatureConversion
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double temperature = sc.nextDouble();
        double kelvin = kelvinCalculations(kelvin);
        double fahrenhuit = fahrenhuitCalculations(fahrenhuit);
        System.out.println(temperature + "Degrees Celsius is equivalent to " + kelvin + " Kelvin and " + fahrenhuit + " Degrees Fahrenhuit");
    }
    public static double kelvinCalculations(double temperature)
    {
        double kelvin = temperature + 273.15;
        return kelvin;
    }
    public static double fahrenhuitCalculations(double temperature)
    {
        double fahrenhuit = (((temperature * 9)/5) + 32 );
        return fahrenhuit;
    }
}
```

This program converts from celsius and fahrenhuit and input/output must be in main. That is what I think is causing most of my problems... Aka passing variables between submodules.

Comment: You're using the variables before they're initialized. Did you mean `kelvinCalculations(temperature)`?

Comment: in both method calls you are using the wrong variable ... the right one would be in both cases the `temperature` variable

Comment: introduce your varialbes before using them: `double kelvin = 0; double fahrenhuit = 0;`

Comment: @DimaSan in this context of the code he wouldnt get the wanted result

Comment: right @mayha, thanks for remark.

Answer (score 4):

The calling code should look like:

```
double kelvin = kelvinCalculations(temperature); 
double fahrenhuit = fahrenhuitCalculations(temperature);
```